# Appointments longer than 24h will lose their exact start and end time when syncing with active sync?

Tags: iphone, calendar, exchange-activesync

We´re just about setting up a McAfee MDM solution to sync the iPhones and iPads of our company with our Exchange servers.

Now when I have an entry in my Outlook calender e.g. from Monday 9 pm to Wednesday 8 am it will show up in my iPhone calendar as a full day event on every of these 3 days.

Both Apple support and McAfee support say this comes from the Active Sync engine used from the MDM. Anyone also had this issue and knows a solution to fix it?